# How to define a ripple drawable for API level < 21

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-view, android-drawable

I assume that I can't have the ripple effect for API level < 21 but there is a default definition for API < 21 ripple drawables?

values-v21 drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/transparent_black_10" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent_white_30" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

A drawable that shows another color when pressed is enough, but it is posible without creating 3 files to define different states?